# How to add fee to order totals in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, order-totals

The following link will describe

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

to add fee to order totals in Magento 1.

Now this functionality is moved to **Quote module** in Magento 2 .

I think still same concept like collect and fetch methods.
Has anyone tried this in Magento 2?

Comment: in magneto2 filedset from quote to order is removed or not working , but i am not sure about collect totals

Comment: This question is too broad, please try to be more specific. What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-extra-fee.html FREE extension

Comment: I developed module for add extra fee to order total. This extra fee will display in order, invoice and creditmemo. you can download from GitHub: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-extrafee/

Comment: Could use the following module which works with all payment methods and shipping country - https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-surcharge-or-additional-fee.html

Comment: @PrincePatel,@Pradeep can we set extra fee or custom tax amount on quote item level?, I am  looking for code how to set custom tax_amount for quote item.

Comment: How to add website/store view scope. i have 3 website and the only want to show fee one website.

Comment: with Mageants [magento 2 extra fee](https://www.mageants.com/extra-fee-for-magento-2.html) extension you can solve your query

Answer (score 130, accepted):

follow below steps it will help you,  in my module, I just added fee column
this will add one row in cart total called fee and also side bar in the checkout page
and also it added fee amount to total amount (fee static value I kept as 100)
once the order is placed total  will be with fee and if you are logged in fronted in order view  you can see fee's new row in the total block but admin side not yet implemented if someone implements, you can post that answer

create `sales.xml` in your module etc folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            
            <item name="fee" instance="Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee" sort_order="150"/>
          
        </group>  
    </section>
</config>
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\cart\totals\fee.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define(
    [
        'Sugarcode_Test/js/view/checkout/summary/fee'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            isDisplayed: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\summary\fee.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: 'Sugarcode_Test/checkout/summary/fee'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode();
            },
            getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('fee').value;
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
            getBaseValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = this.totals().base_fee;
                }
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getBasePriceFormat());
            }
        });
    }
);
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\summary\fee.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko -->

  <tr class="totals fee excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
          
            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            
            
        </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- /ko -->
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\cart\totals\fee.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko -->
<tr class="totals fee excl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;


class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
   /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null; 
    
    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator)
    {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    }
  public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
      
      
        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = 100; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
        
        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);
        
        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    } 
    
    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => 100
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Fee');
    }
}
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sugarcode_Test" setup_version="2.0.6" schema_version="2.0.6">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                
                                
                                <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Sugarcode_Test/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode_Test/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Fee</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                    
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Sugarcode_Test/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode_Test/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Fee</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  
    <body>        
        <referenceContainer name="order_totals">
            <block class="Sugarcode\Test\Block\Sales\Order\Fee" name="fee"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Block\Sales\Order\Fee.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Tax totals modification block. Can be used just as subblock of \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block\Sales\Order;



class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Tax configuration model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Tax\Model\Config
     */
    protected $_config;

    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    protected $_order;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    protected $_source;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Config $taxConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_config = $taxConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Check if we nedd display full tax total info
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function displayFullSummary()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get data (totals) source model
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return $this->_source;
    } 
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_order->getStore();
    }

      /**
     * @return Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_order;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLabelProperties()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getLabelProperties();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getValueProperties()
    {
        return $this->getParentBlock()->getValueProperties();
    }
    
    /**
     * Initialize all order totals relates with tax
     *
     * @return \Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax
     */
     public function initTotals()
    {
        
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
        $this->_source = $parent->getSource();

        $store = $this->getStore();
        
        $fee = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'fee',
                    'strong' => false,
                    'value' => 100,
                    //'value' => $this->_source->getFee(),
                    'label' => __('Fee'),
                ]
            );
     
            $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');

            return $this;
    }

}
```

once the above steps are done run below command this is important else your js & Html files will be missing from pub/static folder. So run below command which will create js and html file in pub/static folder

```
bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

if works  accept my answer which helps others

Comment: you wrote out the module... impressive! +1 for that

Comment: well done praseep

Comment: i selected this answer as accepted answer 4 days before only.but still I’m getting notification as not selected.there is a issue in bounty functionality

Comment: i am not sure, try in flag , that end of my comments there like edit delete flag , try in flag

Comment: Great article Pradeep, what about admin changes as I can't see any admin related changes in the code above?

Comment: hello Pradeep Kumar, great article, but there is one problem with that code, fee add two times into grand total, is there any solution for this?

Comment: How to add condition like if order subtotal greater than equal to $120 then add custom fee discount?

Comment: How to use clear values function? I think in your code this function not used in any where ..

Comment: Has anyone fixed the two time fee applied bug in above code?

Comment: The "Two Times Fee"-bug is in the last lines of  app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Block\Sales\Order\Fee.php...  there's a double occurrence of          `$parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');` Guys, don't just copy-paste stuff, read and understand what you do...

Comment: I have removed that, Still I am getting it twice. any ideas?

Comment: I am sorry, I have to apologize. The "Two Times Fee"-Bug is most probably due to the fact that app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee.php extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal. As you normally have two Addresses in Checkout (Billing and Shipping) the Quote save gets called twice. There was a similar Behaviour in M1, unfortunately the M1-Fix is not applicable here...

Comment: @PradeepKumar do you know how to do this on checkout instead of cart page?

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for such a great tutorial. But I want to apply on a button click. I have created a form after discount and I want to add fee on button click. Fee will be collect by textbox on the form.

Comment: Hello Pardeep, i have followed following url http://webkul.com/blog/display-custom-pricefee-sales-order-view-page/ which is same as your answer. but after i added the last file i.e for the sales order view i get following error on the customer order view page : Notice: Undefined index: class in /var/www/jewel/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php on line 213 can you help on this ?

Comment: delete generation folder

Comment: I want to insert fee in subtotal on **checkbox** is checked can anyone please suggest how to do so.

Comment: I tried to add same label in my account history for invoice page summary, It is coming fine for invoice but not in order info.
\app\code\Dischem\Wicode\view\frontend\layout\sales_order_invoice.xml
with referenceContainer as 'invoice_totals' . 
This is working fine but Order summary is not showing label
any Idea, what I have missed?

Comment: In case people have trouble with the fee/discount being applied twice, see this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42141291/7540890

Comment: Works fine everywhere except on order view page on the frontend, it's not showing in order view. @PradeepKumar

Comment: How to add this Fee field in adminhtml sales orders totals??

Comment: How to add a fee from text box  https://prnt.sc/hfsni5  /Sivajik34/Customfee/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/fee.html

Comment: any one implemented it to appear in backend side ?

Comment: can anyone please tell me where I can place sales.xml file?

Comment: place in Sugarcode\Test\etc folder

Comment: can you give me registration page code so i add in it to run this module

Comment: I copied all the code and make folder and pages but it's not showing anything on cart page so what page or folder I missed please help?

Comment: I want to fetch a price from my custom table and show in cart page please help?

Comment: can you help me in chat ??? appreciated

Comment: Can anyone explaine what happens when an order created? Is just grant total of order changed or are there any entries created for custom price?

Comment: Is there any update one the "doubled fee" issue? I did remove the duplicate method call in Block\Sales\Order\Fee and I also added the code snippet from the answer down below. The fee still gets applied twice.

Comment: @hallleron yes  you have to just comment  $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance); this line and your problem will be solved

Comment: hello , Can you please tell me how extra fee is calculated in order total  i want to know @PradeepKumar

Comment: How to use this same concept when we only want to add this extra fee on CASH on delivery

Comment: @PradeepKumar how to add discount in admin, admin can enter discount amount and click to apply , discount should show on order total summary section

Comment: is there any simple way to add/remove the price on cart page? just to add/remove a single digit it takes a complete module to perform the task.

Comment: Hi, I've added an extra fee using this module but I can't see the extra fee on the order view details in customer my account. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: anyone facing a duplicate issue could check this and update the model  https://github.com/bragento/magento2-cash-on-delivery-fee/blob/develop/Model/Total/CashOnDeliveryFee.php

Comment: Does this module add checkbox on checkout page to select fee.?

Answer (score 5):

Based on above answer i developed custom fee extension.

https://github.com/sivajik34/Custom-Fee-Magento2

Comment: How to add a fee from text box https://prnt.sc/hfsni5

Comment: how to add textbox for adding fee in magento2

Comment: @NagendraKodi I need same extra fee as you mentioned in the comment (https://prnt.sc/hfsni5) How you have achieved that ?

Answer (score 5):

please comment

```
        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
```

form **app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total\Fee.php** for double custom fee issue

Hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Pradeep is very helpful, but misses an important point.

The function Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total::collect() is called twice by Magento's Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteTotalsCollector::collect(), once for each address. At that point it creates a combined total that is stored in the quote table. It does not show up in the order, nor on the website in the checkout.

For this reason it is important to collect the fee in only one of times that collect() is called. This can be done by checking if there are any shipped items available:

```
    $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
```

Add this code at the beginning of your variant of Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total::collect()

Comment: still adding twice

Comment: Any update on this? It is still adding the fee twice. Can't get it to work unfortunately.

Comment: @Patrick van Bergen good spot this solved the problem with dynamic fee not updated to grand total on frondend

Answer (score 4):

I have used the above code for adding the custom fee. Custom fee is dynamic for each order. So i have save the value in the database.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
        <table name="quote" resource="default" engine="innodb">
            <column xsi:type="decimal" name="fee" nullable="true" comment="Custom Tax from webservice"/>
        </table>
        <table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Order">
            <column xsi:type="decimal" name="fee" nullable="true" comment="Custom Tax from webservice"/>
        </table>
</schema>
```

Convert the quote to sales using fieldset.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <!-- Copy quote to sale order fields -->
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="fee">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

Observer to convert quote to sales

```
    <?php

namespace BA\Vertex\Observer\Frontend\Sales;

class QuoteSubmitBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        try {
           
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            $order->setData('fee', $quote->getData('fee'));

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

events.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer instance="BA\Vertex\Observer\Frontend\Sales\QuoteSubmitBefore" name="ba_vertex_quote_submit_before"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

For displaying custom fee in magento admin backend

view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceContainer name="order_totals">
            <block class="BA\Vertex\Block\Sales\Order\Fee" name="fee"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Block class

```
    <?php
namespace BA\Vertex\Block\Sales\Order;

class Fee extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var Order
     */
    protected $_order;
    /**
     * @return Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_order;
    }
    /**
     * Initialize all order totals relates with tax
     *
     * @return \Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax
     */
    public function initTotals()
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        $this->_order = $parent->getOrder();
        $fee = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'fee',
                'strong' => false,
                'value' => $this->_order->getFee(),
                'label' => __('Fee'),
            ]
        );

        $parent->addTotal($fee, 'fee');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: The custom fee set in quote area is missing. Could you please share where to set custom fee in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone who is struggling with 2 times fees issue, try the following code to apply fees in the collect method.

```
$fee = 10;           
$total->addTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
$total->addBaseTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
$total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal());
```

Your collect method should look something like this.

```
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    )
    {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        if (!count($shippingAssignment->getItems())) {
            return $this;
        }

            $fee = 10;           
            $total->addTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
            $total->addBaseTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
            $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal());
            $quote->setFee($fee);          



        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this saved my time a lot.