# Magento 2 - Add Custom Discount to Order Totals on Cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, discount

```
protected function productpointAjax()
{

    $layout = $this->_view->getLayout();
    $this->checkoutSession->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
    $totalsBlock = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Totals')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/totals.phtml');
    return $totalsBlock->toHtml();
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <sales>
         <quote>
            <totals>
                <productpoint>
                    <class>productpoint/quote/address/total/productpoint</class>
                    <after>subtotal</after>
                    <before>tax</before>
                </productpoint>
            </totals>
         </quote>
    </sales>
</config>
```

**Namespace\Modulename\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Productpoint.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ei\Productpoint\Model\Quote\Address\Total;

class Productpoint extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal{

    protected $ProductPointCode = '';
    protected $EstimatePoints  = '';


    public function __construct(
        \Ei\Productpoint\Helper\Data $productpointHelper,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ){

        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->productpointHelper = $productpointHelper;
        $this->moduleStatus = $this->productpointHelper->getModuleStatus();
        $this->minPointsConfig  = $this->productpointHelper->getMinimumPoints();
        $this->productPoints    = $this->productpointHelper->getCustomerProductPointsAssigned();
        $this->ProductPointCode = $this->productpointHelper->getCode();
        $this->EstimatePoints  = $this->checkoutSession->getEstimatePoints();
        $this->PointsRedeem  = $this->checkoutSession->getPointsRedeem();
        $this->PointsPrice  = $this->checkoutSession->getPointsPrice();
    }

    //In function collect() you can add whatever amount you want to the order totals
    public function collect(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address)
    {

        parent::collect($address);

        $this->_setAmount(0);
        $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

        $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
        if (!count($items)) {
            return $this; //this makes only address type shipping to come through
        }

        $quote = $address->getQuote();

                //check if module enabled, minpoints < points assigned and productpoint redeemed only then display in grand_total block        
        if( ($this->ProductPointCode == $this->EstimatePoints) && ($this->moduleStatus == 1) && ($this->minPointsConfig < $this->productPoints) ){

                $exist_amount = $quote->getProductpointAmount();
                $productPointPrice = $this->productpointHelper->getPrice($this->PointsRedeem);
                $balance = $productPointPrice - $exist_amount;

        $address->setProductpointAmount($balance);
        $address->setBaseProductpointAmount($balance);

        $quote->setProductpointAmount($balance);

        $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $address->getProductpointAmount());
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $address->getBaseProductpointAmount());
            }    

    }

    //The function fetch() is used for display purposes
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address)
    {
                //check if module enabled, minpoints < points assigned and productpoint redeemed only then display in grand_total block        
                if(($this->ProductPointCode == $this->EstimatePoints) && ($this->moduleStatus == 1) && ($this->minPointsConfig < $this->productPoints)){

                $amount = $address->getProductpointAmount();
                $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'  => $this->productpointHelper->getCode(),
                'title' => __('Points Redeem ('.$this->PointsRedeem.'&nbsp;points)'),
                'value' => '-'.$amount
        ));

                return $this;
            }    

    }
}
```

It throws below exception

> There has been an error processing your request Notice: Undefined
>   index: components in
>   app\code\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\CartTotalsProcessor.php on line
>   18

Whenever the totals are calculated for a quote, it should also call my class and add custom discount if applicable. The two main functions here 
are `collect()` and `fetch()`. In collect function you add whatever amount you want to the order totals, and fetch() is used for display purposes.

How can I show `custom discount` on `cart` page by adding it to totals block ?

P.S. The above code works well with version 1.8/1.9

Reference link [1](http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-discount-total-magento)/[2](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/)

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this link : '[how to add fee to order totals in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2/117209#117209)'.
This link have detail how to add fee in total you can add your custom discount same way.

Comment: Get error when place order like:The requested Payment Method is not available. ,when applied discount more then 50% of grand total.And in magento backend at payment method  "Minimum Order Total" this is empty.