# Adding product to magento 2 cart programmatically makes its price zero

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, quote

I am adding product to cart in magento 2 programmatically here is the code for that:

```
public function getProduct($productId)
    {
        //\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product

        if ($productId) {
            $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get(
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class
            )->getStore()->getId();
            try {
                return $this->_productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and here is my code for adding product to cart:

```
  $product = $this->getProduct((int)$inputRequest['product']);

                    $this->_request->setParams($inputRequest);
                    $this->_cart->addProduct($product, $inputRequest);
   $this->_cart->save();
```

but when I save the cart, it saves the product in database but the data is zero for everything like price, discount amount and other attributes of items are zero, only quantity is correct which I am putting as input in `$inputRequest`. 
I have also called `collectTotals` and `updateItems` method of `cart` but there is no change in data.

Here is the quote_item table (I included the most important attributes), the most recent product (Impulse duffle) was added programmetically and it has zero price, row_total.

[image]

If I update cart on cart page, then prices are updated. May be I am missing to dispatch some event? Has someone else faced the same issue before?

Comment: Please check this answer:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116841/how-to-re-collect-quote-totals-in-magento-2

Comment: could you please provide result of order item table records related to this order?

Comment: @Furman please see the updated question!