# How to set Dynamic Lable in Order Summary when check out cart in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

[image]

> This 'Charge'(label) is coming from checkout_index_index.xml file
>   code:-

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Abc_Xyz/checkout/cart/totals/fee</item>
<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Charge</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Having same issue, have you got the answer?

Comment: Yes, you can manage this label using js and khockout  follow this link   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2/93349