# Magento 2 : Add Custom Fee Based On Shipping and Billing Address

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address

I already refer this :
[how to add fee to order totals in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2)

But my requirement is diffrent.

I need to add custom fee in order total based on Shipping or Billing address selected by customer during checkout.

I need to add fee based on selected country.
See screen-sort.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried anything ? I don't know who up-votes your question because your question looks not Interesting as my point of view. If you tried something and you got any error then people will try to help you. So don't expect whole answer from peoples.

Comment: @KeyurShah I search for this, but I found result that add fee to cart. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2
using this my requirement not fullfill, So i need help.