# Cash Discount for Payment Method

Tags: module, payment-methods, discount

I need to add a cash discount for a payment method (called "Vorkasse" in German - advance payment is the word in English I guess). The total cart value (excluding shipping costs) should have a discount of 2%.

I found this already here: [how to add fee to order totals in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2)

But it is a fixed rate for all payment methods...

Answer (score 3):

So here's what I found out:

- to apply a discount, you have to create a cart price rule
- cart price rule for payment method was removed (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb65d05d41f30cd6a10fdfffb10b1dd8f42d3a77#diff-6af1fa68376d90ae611de38779431624)
- adding the line **'payment_method' => __('Payment Method'),** in file app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php makes the option visible again - now I can create the price rule
- but: the rule does not appear in checkout; use the accepted answer of this question: [how to add fee to order totals in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2)
- re-deploy static content: rm -rf pub/static/*; rm -rf var/cache; rm -rf var/composer_home; rm -rf var/generation; rm -rf var/page_cache; rm -rf var/view_preprocessed; mmage setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US

It works now. Magento 2 is pretty poor. There are so much bugs and missing features...

Comment: Thank you for your report! Held us. However we are now getting null returned from $model->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod() inside core, so there is no way of actually comparing the condition (returns false).