# Magento-2 : How to update cart total on check-box checked/unchecked

Tags: magento2, checkout, quote

Magento2 - in checkout page, I have one check-box just before the payment method on the checkout payment step. I need to update cart total on check-box check/unchecked.

Currently system is working like once I clicked on check-box, my custom action is call and get an Ajax response with some amount. How can update this amount to cart total after complete this action?

You can share your code/reference here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to reload the order summary total on checkout page?

Comment: I want yo display used wallet amount to sidebar,  but not deduct to order total. because of wallet amount isn't work as discount. Also I want to pass amount to payment method which is minus from grand total. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Currently, Does your module calculate the amount correct or not? Or not implement yet?

Comment: Not any amount display right now but how to show calculated amount on sidebar?

Comment: You can see my module here: https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee

Comment: Yes, but how can show calculated amount on click check-box on checkout page?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93349/33057