# Magento 2.2, How to refresh payment method when Grandtotal is Rs.0?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods

I need refresh PaymentMethod when `GrandTotal` is `Rs.0`?

I have added my js below.

```
    define(
                [
                    'jquery',   
                    'mage/url',
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
                    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information',
                ],
                function (
                        $,
                        urlBuilder,
                        getTotalsAction,
                        fullScreenLoader,
                        getPaymentInformationAction
                        ) {
                    'use strict';

                    return function (isLoading, newValue) {
                        if (newValue) {
                            var use_wallet = 1;
                        } else {
                            var use_wallet = 0;
                        }

                        var serviceUrl = urlBuilder.build('wallet/checkout/totals');
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: serviceUrl,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {use_wallet: use_wallet},
                            success: function (response) {

                                if (response) {
                                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                                    isLoading(false);
                                    getTotalsAction([], deferred);



getPaymentInformationAction().done(function () {
    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
    return true
});
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                isLoading(false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reload payment method by using below JS code

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information'
]



getPaymentInformationAction().done(function () {
    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
    return true
});
```

Comment: I got this error..                  Uncaught TypeError: getPaymentInformationAction(...).done is not a function
    at Object.success (totals.js:55)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
    at done (jquery.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)

Comment: Hi @sureshchikani, Now i have added one checkbox under payment method for wallet amount, when i click my custom checkbox my wallet amount updated, But how to refresh payment method?

Comment: show your JS code

Comment: I have added my js above.

Comment: I see your question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200138/magento-2-how-to-update-cart-total-on-check-box-checked-unchecked But u have solved it?

Comment: I can't see my code in your JS.

Comment: Now i have added bro.... But this throw Uncaught TypeError: getPaymentInformationAction(...).done is not a function.

Comment: Throw this error   Uncaught TypeError: getPaymentInformationAction.done is not a function.

Comment: Please help me?

Comment: Please explain this question answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160479/magento-2-how-to-refresh-payment-method-on-some-condition