# Magento2 : How to add my custom template in order summary page after total

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to add my custom template on checkout page in order summary just after `Total` as shown in screenshot :

[image]

In this template `.phtml` file I want to add some conversion depend on payment gateway just to display only to customer.

How can I do that?

Comment: We cannot include the `phtml` because the checkout Page used Knockout html template. We should build the js to get the result.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, please post how can I build js for my requirement.

Comment: The problem is here: `depend on payment gateway`. So, when the client chooses the payment, the custom total will re-calculate?

Comment: As I said I just want to display the price which will be show on payment gateway to customer, payment gateway conversion is done in its module already, don't want to update cart total and anything else.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, Can you please suggest how can I use ajax in `.html` file ?

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But, currently, I'm working on my tasks in my company. So, I will suggest you at night.

Comment: Can you please post your previous answer again?

Answer (score 3):

If we take a look the Json config of xml layout on checkout page:

[image]

As we can see, we can add the custom content to `itemsBefore` area.

For example code:

**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="testcustom" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/summary/custom</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/custom.js**

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Checkout/summary/custom'
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/custom.html**

```
<div>Test Test Here</div>
```

Comment: Can I add `.phtml` file in place of `.html` file?

Comment: I do not try but I think we cannot. Try to use html and use Cms content.

Comment: I tried but not working, I need to load cart session here and some calculation, Please suggest How can I add `.phtml` below `Total`?

Comment: `I tried but not working`? The message did not show? I'm pretty sure it will show.

Comment: I meant to say `.html` is working properly, but when I tried with `.phtml` it is not working. And I need to add `.phtml` file not html as I have to do some php calculation here.

Comment: Yes. `.phtml` cannot work in this case. Magento uses Knockout template. So, you cannot use `.phtml`.

Comment: A good example for you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93349/33057

Comment: But this example for update cart total, I don't want to update total, I just want to take cart total from session and apply some conversion depend on payment gateway just to display to customer only.

Comment: I think it's better to create a new question. I will take a look at it. Because your issue is more complicated now.

Comment: How do you get that "Json config of xml layout"? Is much easier to interpret this than the crazy magneto core xml files