# Magento 2 - Update quantity and totals of cart page without page reload?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart

In Magento2 - We need to update main cart on change of quantity by Ajax without click on "**Update Cart Button**" and without reloading the page, 
Below my code in this code only update cart subtotal but not updated cart page summery sidebar subtotal.

```
 require(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'], function ($) {
    // $("#submitbutton").hide();
    var form = $('form#form-validate');
    var qtyfields = $('input.qty');
    $('.page.messages').each(function () {
        var thismessage = $(this);
        thismessage.attr('id', 'messages');
    });

    form.find(qtyfields).each(function (e) {
        var thisfield = $(this);
        $(this).change(function () {
            console.log('change detected');
            form.submit();
        });

    });
    $(document).on('submit','form#form-validate', function (e) {
        var thisfield = $(this);
        var thisiteminfo = thisfield.closest(".item-info");
        var thissubtotal = thisiteminfo.children(".subtotal");
        var formsubtotals = $(this).find('.subtotal');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);
                var totals = $(parsedResponse).find("#cart-totals");
                $("#cart-totals").replaceWith(totals);
                console.log(totals);
                //location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
        console.log('form submitted');
    });
});
```

Please help me for find best solution.

Comment: You can log parsedResponse?

Comment: Yes, cart quantity updated correctly but cart subtotal and cat page summery section subtotal not updated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deferred operation with getTotalsAction or totals-processor?

It's showing ajax process in your cart  after calcul

you can use it like this (i minimize your code, just to show you how to use these functions.)  :

```
require(["jquery", "Magento_Customer/js/customer-data","jquery/jquery-storageapi","Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default","Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache","Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote","Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals"], function ($,defaultTotal,cartCache,quote,getTotalsAction) {
$(document).on("submit","form#form-validate", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: "post",
        success: function (res) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // this show ajax loader and reload price in cart
    getTotalsAction([], deferred);
    // this one too 
    defaultTotal.estimateTotals();
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
    console.log("form submitted");
});});
```

I suggest you to show this post for updating price in cart : [How to add fee to order totals in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2) 
and this one : https://github.com/sivajik34/Custom-Fee-Magento2