# How to make extra fee on specific payment method : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extrafee

How to make extra fee on specific payment method and this fee appearing in `frontend`, `order email`, `backend(order, invoice)` ?

More extensions not have a full features as I mentioned in my questions. Also I followed this question [how to add fee to order totals in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento2)

but the correct answer does not support admin side as I need in my question. he mentioned that in his answer.

Comment: You can follow following extension https://github.com/sivajik34/Custom-Fee-Magento2, i have used it once myself.

Comment: this may be helpful  https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee

Comment: @Piyush, I edited my question. also the extension you mentioned has a problem which not display fee in admin side (order, invoice)

Comment: Do you want COD extra fee ?

Comment: Not COD, but extra fee on a specific payment.

Comment: Go for extension then https://magecomp.com/magento-2-payment-fee.html