# want to show values in shopping cart page from custom table

Tags: database, cart, shipping

Want to show values in the shopping cart page from the custom table.

So I need any tutorials or extension or any code please help me anyone.

Comment: Please clarify the question as what type of value it is "updating cart total" or just display value on "cart page". you can achieve this thing by using `plugin`  of cart methods

Comment: created a table and set two values now I want to show these values in cart page like extra charges and ad in total price as well on every product purchase

Comment: Yes then you can achieve this thing by plugin & observer of magento you can reference this link to apply charges on total http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

Comment: Also you can check this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2

Comment: Also you can check this question magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/
in this answer please tell me where i can placed sales.xml file???

Comment: You have to put "create `sales.xml` in you Module `etc` folder" they have given this hint.

Comment: If my comment is helpful then you can upvote! so other user can get useful.

Comment: can you please help me in chat i need to done this with dynamic fields ??