# For what there is the sales.xml file?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.2

For what there is the **sales.xml** file? In the documentation, I can not find anything about this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sales.xml contains all kind of total objects like discount, subtotal, grandtotal, tax which display on cart page or order details page in admin and many more places. I can say everthing that is related to total in quote or order defines in this file.

You can add your custom total object as well using this file.  Check below link for more details

[How to add fee to order totals in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2)

Let me know in case you need more explanation on this :)

Comment: If I'd like to do something like "TOTAL WEIGHT" it should be done also this way?

Comment: Yes it can be done from this