# How to get cart grand total(Summary) without shipping cost in checkout/cart page in Magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I want to get cart grand total(Summary) without **shipping cost** in checkout/cart page in Magento2.1.7?

Comment: You can get idea from this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2

Answer (score -1):

KnockOut js requests the Total from the getValue() function in

> vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total.js.

If you only want to change the Total on Cart, you need to override

> vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.js .

This js extends the first one so you can make changes that will only be applicable on the cart.
Here's a good example on how to replace a js if you don't already have a custom theme: https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/override-core-javascript-files-magento-2.html

Your modified js should look like :

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */

define([
    'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
], function (Component, quote, totals) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        totals: quote.getTotals(),

        /**
         * @override
         */
        isDisplayed: function () {
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Remove shipping cost from cart Total
         * @returns {*|String}
         */
        getValue: function () {
            var price = 0;

            if (this.totals()) {
                price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value - totals.getSegment('shipping').value;
            }

            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
    });
});
```

This will override the function getValue(), only for the cart.