# Base currency rate is not showing in admin order summary : custom added fee

Tags: magento2.1.5, order-summary, extrafee

I have followed below link to add a custom fee to order.

> [How to add fee to order totals in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2)

Custom fee is added perfectly and showing in admin order summary without any issue.

Now I Have a different store view for China and I have ordered from it, custom fee is adding and showing in admin but its base rate is not showing or added in order totals, is there something which I forgot to add.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding extra fee using the below method.

```
$fee = new DataObject(
    [
        'code' => 'my_code',
        'strong' => true,
        'value' => 100,
        'label' => __('Import Duty')
    ]
);
$parent->addTotal($fee, 'doyenhub_codcharges');
```

I need to pass one more parameter `base_value` to $fee Dataobject as below

```
$fee = new DataObject(
    [
        'code' => 'my_code',
        'strong' => true,
        'value' => 100,
        'base_value' => 10,
        'label' => __('Import Duty')
    ]
);
$parent->addTotal($fee, 'doyenhub_codcharges');
```