# How to get the applied custom discount amount in observer?

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, discount

I followed the steps in the below link to apply custom discount

[https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93349/21007][1].

But I need to get the applied custom discount amount in the observer
event of **`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`**.

how to achieve this?