# Custom store credit get applied twice on the payment gatway total in magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment, grand-total, store-credit

When applying for store credit/custom fees(custom module) in one-page checkout in Magento 2. It gets applied correctly on the grand total. But when pay using a payment gateway(razor pay), my store credit gets applied twice on that payment value.

Screenshot for store credit applied correctly on the grand total.
[image]

Screenshot for when pay using razor pay my grand total and payment total(store credit get applied twice) get different.
[image]

I followed this for reference link
[How to add fee to order totals in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2/93349#93349)