# Add custom row to Order View on Frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, sales-order, xml, phtml

I have my own custom discount, and on checkout I can use it. When I place the order, I see that grand total is changed, but me need to show discount.
I want to paste it between subtotal and shipping.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this file in your custom module

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php

and you can override this function `_initTotals()` only there, you need to create below files.

Create `di.xml` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Totals" />
</config>
```

Create Block file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Order/Totals.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
{
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $source = $this->getSource();

        $this->_totals = [];
        $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            ['code' => 'subtotal', 'value' => $source->getSubtotal(), 'label' => __('Subtotal')]
        );


        /*Here you can add your custom code */  
        $this->_totals['custom'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            ['code' => 'custom', 'value' => "Custom", 'label' => __('Custom')]
        );
        /*Here you can add your custom code */  

        /**
         * Add shipping
         */
        if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
            $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'shipping',
                    'field' => 'shipping_amount',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                    'label' => __('Shipping & Handling'),
                ]
            );
        }

        /**
         * Add discount
         */
        if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0) {
            if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
            } else {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount');
            }
            $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'discount',
                    'field' => 'discount_amount',
                    'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                    'label' => $discountLabel,
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'grand_total',
                'field' => 'grand_total',
                'strong' => true,
                'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
                'label' => __('Grand Total'),
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Base grandtotal
         */
        if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
            $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                    'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total to be Charged'),
                    'is_formated' => true,
                ]
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: please use at least a parent::_initTotals combined with some methods for pushing the new element at the right position. With this example you need to take care about every magento update, which may could change the original file.

Comment: Approve, if this works for you! Thanks

Comment: Thanks you! It's work for me

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: This is working perfectly, Can you please help me to add the same in order invoice and sales order email.

Answer (score 0):

With custom discount you mean, you didnt add a new discount via salesrules or something like this, but added a new total fee, which needs to be applied to the quote totals, to be displayed in the checkout ?

To achieve this you need to create a new total model, and attach it to the totals inside a modules `etc/sales.xml`.

There are several nice guides how to do this, for example this one:
[How to add fee to order totals in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2)

Comment: I have column in table 'quote', and when we see success page I add this discount to table 'sales_order', me need only to show it.

Comment: Adding a total should always be done by adding a new total model, any other way is far more complicated, or very bad for further extendability. It sounds like you would only need a very simple model to get/set the discount for an quote/order.