# How to add custom fee on checkout based on Dropdown Selection?

Tags: magento2, checkout, drop-downs, extrafee, change

I want to add custom fee on checkout based on Drop-down value.

[image]

[image]

Like this based on selection i want to change custom fee value based on drop-down selection.

Comment: which extension u are using for custom fee?

Comment: Created a custom extension followed this article https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2