# how to change cart summary custom field value?

Tags: magento2.3.4

how can I change the cart summary custom field value at the checkout cart page?

I got a reference from this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92774/how-to-add-fee-to-order-totals-in-magento-2)

**Test/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/fee.html**

```
<!-- ko if: isDisplayed() -->
<!-- ko if: isTaxEnabled() -->
<!-- ko if: isDisplayBoth() -->
<tr class="totals fee excl" >
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: getFeeLabel() + ' ' + getExFeeLabel()"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="totals fee incl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: getFeeLabel() + ' ' + getInFeeLabel()"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getInFormattedPrice()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: isDisplayBoth() -->
<!-- ko if: displayExclTax() -->
<tr class="totals fee excl" >
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: getFeeLabel()"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: displayInclTax() -->
<tr class="totals fee incl">
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: getFeeLabel()"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getInFormattedPrice()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: isTaxEnabled() -->
<tr class="totals fee excl" >
    <th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: getFeeLabel()"></th>
    <td class="amount">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice()"></span>
    </td>
</tr>   
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Test/Module/Model/Quote/Total/Fee.php**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Model\Quote\Total;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;

class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $helperData;
    protected $_priceCurrency;
    protected $taxHelper;
    private   $taxCalculator;

    /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Data $helperData,
        \Ncode\GSTtax\Helper\Tax $helperTax,
        \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculator,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->quoteValidator            = $quoteValidator;
        $this->_priceCurrency            = $priceCurrency;
        $this->helperData                = $helperData;
        $this->taxHelper                 = $helperTax;
        $this->taxCalculator             = $taxCalculator;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    )
    {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        if (!count($shippingAssignment->getItems())) {
            return $this;
        }

        $enabled            = $this->helperData->isModuleEnabled();
        $GstIn              = $this->helperData->getGstIn();        
        $minimumOrderAmount = $this->helperData->getMinimumOrderAmount();
        $GstRegion          = $this->helperData->getGstRegion();
            
        if($Cartinfo        = $this->helperData->getCart()->getQuote()){
            $items          = $Cartinfo->getAllItems();
            foreach($items as $item) {
               $product = $this->helperData->getLoadProduct($item->getProductId());       
               $hsnCode = $product->getHsnCode(); 
               //echo $hsnCode;               
            }            
        }        

        $subtotal = $total->getTotalAmount('subtotal'); 
            if($hsnCode){
                if ($enabled && $GstIn && $minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal){        
                $fee = $this->helperData->getGSTtax(); //Get GST Rate from Backend
                if(is_numeric($fee)){            
                    $fee = $subtotal * $fee / 100;                   
                }
                
                $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
                $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $fee);
                $total->setFee($fee);
                $quote->setFee($fee);            

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $productMetadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface');
                $version = (float)$productMetadata->getVersion();

                if($version > 2.1)
                {
                    //$total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $fee);
                }
                else
                {
                    $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $fee);
                }

                if ($this->taxHelper->isTaxEnabled()) {
                    $address = $this->_getAddressFromQuote($quote);
                    $this->_calculateTax($address, $total);

                    $extraTaxables = $address->getAssociatedTaxables();
                    $extraTaxables[] = [
                        'code' => 'fee',
                        'type' => 'fee',
                        'quantity' => 1,
                        'tax_class_id' => $this->taxHelper->getTaxClassId(),
                        'unit_price' => $fee,
                        'base_unit_price' => $fee,
                        'price_includes_tax' => false,
                        'associated_item_code' => false
                    ];

                    $address->setAssociatedTaxables($extraTaxables);
                }

            }
        }else{

        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {

        $enabled = $this->helperData->isModuleEnabled();
        $minimumOrderAmount = $this->helperData->getMinimumOrderAmount();
        $subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
        $fee = $quote->getFee();
        $address = $this->_getAddressFromQuote($quote);

        $result = [];
        if ($enabled && ($minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal) && $fee) {            
            //echo $fee; die();
            $result = [
                'code' => 'fee',
                'title' => $this->helperData->getFeeLabel(),
                'value' => $fee
            ];

            if ($this->taxHelper->isTaxEnabled() && $this->taxHelper->displayInclTax()) {
                 $result [] = [
                    'code' => 'fee',
                    'value' => $fee + $address->getFeeTax(),
                    'title' => __($this->helperData->getFeeLabel()),
                ];
            }
            if ($this->taxHelper->isTaxEnabled() && $this->taxHelper->displayBothTax()) {
                $result [] = [
                    'code' => 'fee',
                    'value' => $fee + $address->getFeeTax(),
                    'title' => __($this->helperData->getFeeLabel()),
                ];
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('GST');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     */
    protected function clearValues(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);

    }
    protected function _getAddressFromQuote(Quote $quote)
    {
        return $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
    }

    protected function _calculateTax(Address $address, Total $total)
    {
        $taxClassId = $this->taxHelper->getTaxClassId();
        if (!$taxClassId) {
            return $this;
        }

        $taxRateRequest = $this->_getAddressTaxRequest($address);
        $taxRateRequest->setProductClassId($taxClassId);

        $rate = $this->taxCalculator->getRate($taxRateRequest);



        $baseTax = $this->taxCalculator->calcTaxAmount(
            $total->getBaseTotalAmount('fee'),
            $rate,
            false,
            true
        );
        $tax = $this->taxCalculator->calcTaxAmount(
            $total->getTotalAmount('fee'),
            $rate,
            false,
            true
        );



        //$total->setBaseMcPaymentfeeTaxAmount($baseTax);
        $total->setFeeTax($tax);

        $appliedRates = $this->taxCalculator->getAppliedRates($taxRateRequest);
        $this->_saveAppliedTaxes($address, $appliedRates, $tax, $baseTax, $rate);

        $total->addBaseTotalAmount('tax', $baseTax);
        $total->addTotalAmount('tax', $tax);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getAddressTaxRequest($address)
    {
        $addressTaxRequest = $this->taxCalculator->getRateRequest(
            $address,
            $address->getQuote()->getBillingAddress(),
            $address->getQuote()->getCustomerTaxClassId(),
            $address->getQuote()->getStore()
        );
        return $addressTaxRequest;
    }

    protected function _saveAppliedTaxes(
        Address $address,
        $applied,
        $amount,
        $baseAmount,
        $rate
    ) {
        $previouslyAppliedTaxes = $address->getAppliedTaxes();
        $process = 0;
        if(is_array($previouslyAppliedTaxes)) {
            $process = count($previouslyAppliedTaxes);
        }
        foreach ($applied as $row) {
            if ($row['percent'] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!isset($previouslyAppliedTaxes[$row['id']])) {
                $row['process'] = $process;
                $row['amount'] = 0;
                $row['base_amount'] = 0;
                $previouslyAppliedTaxes[$row['id']] = $row;
            }

            if ($row['percent'] !== null) {
                $row['percent'] = $row['percent'] ? $row['percent'] : 1;
                $rate = $rate ? $rate : 1;

                $appliedAmount = $amount / $rate * $row['percent'];
                $baseAppliedAmount = $baseAmount / $rate * $row['percent'];
            } else {
                $appliedAmount = 0;
                $baseAppliedAmount = 0;
                foreach ($row['rates'] as $rate) {
                    $appliedAmount += $rate['amount'];
                    $baseAppliedAmount += $rate['base_amount'];
                }
            }

            if ($appliedAmount || $previouslyAppliedTaxes[$row['id']]['amount']) {
                $previouslyAppliedTaxes[$row['id']]['amount'] += $appliedAmount;
                $previouslyAppliedTaxes[$row['id']]['base_amount'] += $baseAppliedAmount;
            } else {
                unset($previouslyAppliedTaxes[$row['id']]);
            }
        }
        $address->setAppliedTaxes($previouslyAppliedTaxes);
    }
}
```

**Test/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/fee.html**

```
<!-- ko -->

  <tr class="totals fee excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: getValue()"></span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">

            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>


        </td>
    </tr>   

<!-- /ko -->
```

[image]

Comment: what is the flow of get this value? how can i debug that exactly from where this value comes?

Answer (score 0):

the value are come from return fee variable in fetch function

here :

```
            $result = [
                'code' => 'fee',
                'title' => $this->helperData->getFeeLabel(),
                'value' => $fee // here the variable
            ];
```

and you may debug that variable with the logger

is that what you looking for?

Comment: yes value is coming from here you are right

Comment: in js also this value are comes?